# Prove that a set is not bounded from above.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the set $ A=\{y \in \Bbb{R}: y = \frac{1-x}{x}, x \in \Bbb{R} \}$ is not bounded above. Below is my idea, is that true?

Assume by contradiction that A is bounded above, then there exists a real number b such that $y \lt b$ for all y in A, implies that $\frac{1-x}{x} \lt b$ for all positive real number, follows that $\frac{1}{x} \lt b+1$ for all positive real number x, it means that $1/x$ is bounded above. Since $1/x$ is also a positive real number and set of positive real number is not bounded above, thus it is impossible that $1/x$ is bounded above. Therefore A is not bounded above.

Comment: You should use proper MathJax to mark up the math in your question. Most of it is not visible because you have not used the markup properly.

Comment: What theorems can you use?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{1-x}{x}=\infty$$
which should (intuitively, at least) demonstrate the unboundedness.

In particular, note that $$\frac{1-x}{x}=y$$
has solution $x=\frac{1}{1+y}$. So if $b$ is an upper bound, then picking $x=\frac{1}{1+b+\epsilon}\in\mathbb{R}^+$ for any $\epsilon>0$ yields a greater number. Contradiction.